# How to view the 360 photo inside the sphere in unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a sphere and I want to view the 360 image inside the sphere . I had centered the camera inside the sphere , so that i can rotate in 3 axis.

But the image is showing outside the sphere.

Comment: You could try make it a SkyBox

Comment: You need a correctly UV'd inverted sphere. You can get them for basically free on the asset store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the concept called shaders to flip the normals the sphere so that you can view the photo inside the sphere.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36423846/flip-normals-in-unity-3d-spheres) is the link to fliping the normals.