# Standing inside an Object without clipping

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

My Application is a simulation of a 3D-Audio cage we have in our lab at uni.
To best simulate it, we made it a wireframe-sphere.

I need to be able to stand inside the cage, but if my Sphere is around my Camera, it clips, so it doesn't render until i move away.
I also need to be able to Rotate it, but not move it.

Is there a way to disable clipping for this case? What else can i try to get the desired result?

I've tried to set the clipping pane for the camera to 0, but 0.01 is the lowest it can be.

Also I've tried to use a transparent shader, both tries left me the same problem of the object clipping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Object visibility when inside

> Is there a way to disable clipping for this case? What else can i try
>   to get the desired result?

You can invert the normals of the sphere. Or model a sphere with normals on the inside and the outside if you want to look at it from both sides.

Another solution could be to use a shader with disabled backface culling (`Cull off`).

This stackoverflow answer might be helpful: [Flip Normals in Unity 3D/spheres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36423846/flip-normals-in-unity-3d-spheres)

#### Missing Manipulation Handler (MRTK)

If I understand the `ManipulationHandler` correct, you can make a smaller sphere with a `ManipulationHandler` inside the larger sphere and copy the transform changes to the larger sphere.

If you want to keep the larger sphere at the same place don't copy the position changes.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer aalmighty! I can now see my Sphere with Cull set to off, but still can't rotate it from inside. Gonna try to play with the normals later to see if that changes anything.

Comment: Glad to help. If it solved your problem, please accept the answer.

Comment: For rotation look at [Tansform.Rotate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html). I don't know what your exact problem is. Can you elaborate in your Question?

Comment: Turning Cull to off just solved the visual part of my problem.
I need to stand inside the sphere and want to be able to manipulate it from the inside (i want to rotate it). 
My Sphere has the Manipulationhandler Script attached and is perfectly rotatable from outside of the sphere. Is it possbile for me to manipulate it from the inside? 
In case that wasn't clear aswell, i've created a little test-project running on Unity 2019.2.f1 and MRTK V2 for demonstration here: https://github.com/Jindorf/ManipulateSphereFromInside

Comment: thanks, that definitely works. I think having "handles" (smaller spheres) to manipulate the main-sphere is fine for now.